# Runtime Error 13 type mismatch Excel

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I hope you can help I have the below piece of code and I am getting **runtime error 13** on this line

```
If Sheets("Input").Range("A11:C100").Value = "" Then
```

What I am trying to achieve is to not let a user save the Excel workbook without populating the cells in the range ("A11:C100") The code works fine if it is just ("A11") but if I increase the range I get the error.

The rest of my code is below any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

'Step 1: Check to see if Cell A1 is blank
    If Sheets("Input").Range("A11:C100").Value = "" Then

'Step 2: Blank: cancel the Close and tell the user
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Cells A11 to C100 can not be blank"
'Step 3: Not Blank; Save and Close
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

Pic of sheet 
[image]

Comment: Will you consider to loop and check all cells? you cannot compare a value with a range.  Example like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx

Comment: @ Alex: Thank you for the help. I would consider a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sheets("Input").Range("A11:C100").Value` returns a `Variant` array with all cells content in the range, so you can't compare it to a string like `""`

- if you need to check if *at least one* cell of the range is populated then

  instead of:

  ```
  If Sheets("Input").Range("A11:C100").Value = "" Then
  ```

  use

  ```
  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Input").Range("A11:C100")) = 0 Then
  ```
- if you need to check if *all* cells of the range are populated then

  instead of:

  ```
  If Sheets("Input").Range("A11:C100").Value = "" Then
  ```

  use

  ```
  If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Input").Range("A11:C100")) < Sheets("Input").Range("A11:C100").Count Then
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I need to check that _all_ cells are populated. the code you gave me `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Input").Range("A11:C100")) = Sheets("Input").Range("A11:C100").Count Then` did not work it just turn the VBA area blank and did the same to the excel sheet have i done something wrong?

Comment: sorry there should be a "<" instead of a "=". see edited answer. Not clear what does _"it just turn the VBA area blank"_ mean, though.

Comment: @3598756: The amended code worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your time and skills. Much respect from Dublin. :-) The "_It just turns blank_" the VBA editor just went white as if no code was there and the excel sheet went to a grey background as if waiting to open a new file. But it is fixed now, Again thank you so much for the assistance

Comment: Ha Ha:-)  Yep. That's me Marcoing and VBAin for my life :-P